# A custom action that reads the file and stores a value in session obj. Is there a way to use it as a property while invoking othr custom action

Tags: wix

```
<CustomAction I'd=readValue binaryKey = custom.dll 
    DllEntryy = readfilevalue Execute= deferred Return = 
  check/>

// // In a .cs file code to read the file having method
```

//    readfilevalue.
   //     I am setting 
       Customsession.writesessionvalue(key, value);

```
//   In another .wxs file invoking executables
  <Custom Action = someExe After= someOtherExe>
         <!CDATA[  key < someValue]>
  <Custom>
```

//  Can I get the key value in this Custom tag? If no then 
    //  how can I get the value please suggest.

Comment: To get people to help you, you should write a clear title, explanation what the issue is, what's your code and what have you done to solve your issue. This on the other hand looks like "here's dump of my stuff. solve it and I'll wait for results".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Yes, please add more explanation

Answer (score 0):

No, there is [very limited information flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/obtaining-context-information-for-deferred-execution-custom-actions) between deferred actions (@Execute="deferred") and the shared Windows Installer session. That flow includes sending a few properties to the action (including CustomActionData), and receiving progress information and a success or failure from it, but will not carry arbitrary data like you describe.

Your options, as I see them:

- Make the first custom action immediate so it can take part in the planning. This won't work if the action requires elevated privileges, or access to something put in place by another deferred action, but is otherwise the most "correct" way to do this. Note that if the data itself can be read by existing search patterns (like RegistrySearch), that's even better than an immediate custom action.
- Merge the two actions, so there isn't any need for such a flow of information.
- Use unsupported hacks, like sharing a file location outside of Windows Installer that both actions can access. Then you can send information through that. Note that cleanup of this can be hard to get correct, and that its unsupported nature may result in other problems in esoteric scenarios. (The link about obtaining context information alludes to why.)